# How to Install Whoops in Laravel 6 and Above Versions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, whoops, laravel-6.2

I have been Working on the Laravel Framework Since **5.4**

Here is the History of Laravel Versions And Error Handlers

- 4.0 - 4.2 - **filp/whoops**
- 5.0 - 5.4 - **symfony/error-handler**
- 5.5 - 5.8 - **filp/whoops**

And By the Relese of **Laravel 6.0** they have introduced the new error page Called [Ignition](https://github.com/facade/ignition)

And this package has built in advanced Debugging. But obiviuously this is Done by **VueJS**.

So At the time Debugging the Api Request in Postman I am not Getting Anything in the Preview.

So is there any Way to **Switch to Whoops in the Laravel 6.0 and Future Versions**.

Because there is Option to Switch to Ignition even in the **Older version of laravel projects**

using the Below code in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`

```
protected function whoopsHandler()
{
    try {
        return app(\Whoops\Handler\HandlerInterface::class);
    } catch (\Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException $e) {
        return parent::whoopsHandler();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

luckily, since filp/whoops is still in your composer.json (or at least it was in mine) all you have to do is run `composer remove facade/ignition` and whoops will take over again.

if not, reinstall filp/whoops with `composer require filp/whoops --dev`, and remove ignition and that should be it.

Comment: In Laravel 6.2 I was getting this Process Exception error page with no info in it. Now that I removed ignition, whoops took over and I could see the errors.